# Highcharts create custom yAxis labels

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, yaxis

I want to create following chart example, the xAxis and lines are no problem - thats already done. But I just can't get the custom yAxis label configuration get to work. Could someone provide an example how to do that with highcharts?

[image: Highchart Example]

I tried something like this in my Axis options, but didn't get it to work like in the example picture:

```
yAxis: {
  tickPositioner() {
    return [1e-8, 0.000001, 0.0001, 0.01, 1, 100, 10000];
  },
  min: 0,
  labels: {
    reserveSpace: true,
    formatter() {
      return this.value;
    },
  },
}
```

the result of the above code is something like this:

[image: Example result image of highcharts]

Strange is, that code is coming the above example very near:

```
tickPositions: [-8, -7, -4, -2, 0, 1, 2, 4],
tickPositioner: null,
```

Note: It's hard to provide a example fiddle in here because the series I have for this are non-public and  the dataset is likely 4000-8000 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for the `logarithmic` y-axis type.

You can enable the option in the below way:

```
  yAxis: {
    type: 'logarithmic'
  }
```

However, to show negative values, you will need to add a small extension. Useful thread: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=49524

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9pgujcyd/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes#logarithmic

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.type

Comment: Okay that hint was very useful, with the logarithmic axis type i get at least a view where the chart is centered but the numbers are way to high. How could I manage that my starting point is 1e-8 and the max point is on 10000? I tried many of the examples with Tick Intervals and tickPositioner but I don't get how to really set static labels like in the first example Screenshot.

Comment: Hi @koby, Please check and add your potential comments in this issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/17364 You can achieve the wanted result by using `Math.log10`, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/96qazg0r/